# Cannot insert a null into column — Informix

Tags: informix

I was working on program for bill generation of vendors where a library program code is called for inserting data into a table t_job that stores records for  some important jobs like purchase order generation etc.

The problem is that this library code for inserting data into a table `t_job` gets called from many different 4ge programs and from different users but I am facing a peculiar problem for a newly created user.

I am getting an error "Cannot insert a null into column (t_job.username)" for this user.

The program that deals with  inserting data into t_job has some lines of code that I find worth mentioning with regard to the problem.

```
select username into _user from sysusers where username = user

insert into t_job values(_user,
                         _job_key1,
                         _job_key2,
                         _cd,
                         today,
                         _time)
```

It's driving me nuts why only in this case username for t_jobs is showing as null.

I looked into the sysusers table in sysuser database and found 2 rows there as shown below:

```
username  informix
usertype  D
priority  9
password
defrole

username  public
usertype  C
priority  5
password
defrole
```

Any help in this regard is highly regarded.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the `sysusers` table has just two rows, the `SELECT` statement will only set the variable `_user` when `informix` runs the code.

Recommended fix:

```
INSERT INTO t_job VALUES(USER, _job_key1, _job_key2, _cd, TODAY, _time)
```

The names `USER` and `TODAY` are built-in zero-argument functions (keywords) that return the current user name and the current date.  With the change of `_user` to `USER`, you no longer need the bogus `SELECT`.  You might not need the `_user` variable at all, either.  I'd also look askance at the `_time` variable, though you have to work harder to replace it (`CURRENT HOUR TO MINUTE` should do the job).

Comment: My problem persists because I wanted to understand why the insert code is throwing error only in case of a new user while the same code is working for numerous other users..also i would desist from changing a library program that works just fine

Comment: I can't see enough code to know why it works for other users.  It doesn't make much sense. The reason to fix the code is that it isn't working correctly all the time, and it is doing work that is unnecessary.

Comment: does USER return current user name in caps?

Comment: Yes, it does.  Also in lower-case; I4GL is case-insensitive.

Comment: i tried using USER as a key word but it's not working..might be due to version of Informix we are using..

Comment: Check the manuals too. I was able to run `SELECT USER FROM Dual` on Informix 12.10 on a Mac and got my username as the output. You may need to spell Dual as `sysmaster:informix.sysdual`.  You were using it anyway in your SELECT statement, weren't you?

Comment: yeah ..select statement was working fine but I was trying to get the value of user in a char variable ,same was as taking TODAY in a variable..and the same isn't working

Comment: In I4GL, you'd use: `SELECT USER INTO _user FROM sysmaster:informix.sysdual` to select the result into the variable `_user`.  I was using my `sqlcmd` (essentially, a DB-Access work-alike) instead of I4GL.  With big enough receiving variables, you could select TODAY into a string too.